# how to reach a specialized page in selenium of Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath, web-crawler

Currently i want to go to page 123 of the site: http://www.landchina.com/default.aspx?tabid=351
I'm sorry it's in Chinese but it may not concern with this problem.

In the buttom of this page, we can see a list of 1,2,3,... and a text area which we can click on the text area and then input "123" in the text area. Then we just hit the "GO" buttom besides and it will go to page 123.

I want to imitate this process in Python 2.7 with selenium. When I tried to pass a value "123" to the text area, I find that this input text area doesn't have a name or an id. The related part of the page source is as follows:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr>
<td align="right" class="pager" valign="bottom" style="width:40%;overflow:hidden;">共12318页&nbsp;当前只显示200页&nbsp;共369525条记录</td>
<td align="left" class="pager" valign="bottom" style="width:60%"> 
<a disabled="disabled" style="margin-right:5px;">首页</a>
<a disabled="disabled" style="margin-right:5px;">上页</a>
<span style="color: red;font-weight: bold;margin-right: 5px;">1</span>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',2)" style="margin-right:5px;">2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',3)" style="margin-right:5px;">3</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',4)" style="margin-right:5px;">4</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',5)" style="margin-right:5px;">5</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',6)" style="margin-right:5px;">6</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',7)" style="margin-right:5px;">7</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',8)" style="margin-right:5px;">8</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',9)" style="margin-right:5px;">9</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',10)" style="margin-right:5px;">10</a>
<span><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',11)"style="margin-right:5px;">...</a></span>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',2)" style="margin-right:5px;">下页</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',200)" style="margin-right:5px;">尾页</a>
<input type="text" style="width:30px;" value="1" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13)QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',this.value,200);"/>
<input type="button" value="go" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',this.previousSibling.value,200)"/> 
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

The last three lines containing two "input" is my target. Because it can't be located by name or id, I tried to use xpath. My code is:

```
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
loc="http://www.landchina.com/default.aspx?tabid=351"
browser.get(loc)

box=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']") # find the text area
box.click()
box.send_keys("123") # send 123 to the text area

go=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button']") # find the "GO" button
go.click()
content=browser.page_source
print content
```

But Chrome doesn't input the number "123" in the textarea and the website stays at page 1. Could anyone know how to handle such situation? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to rely on the `go` button and get the first *preceding sibling* with `@type='text'`:

```
//input[@type='button' and @value='go']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='text']
```

Also, an alternative to `send_keys()` option, you can set the text area value [through javascript](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script):

```
box = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button' and @value='go']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='text'] ")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '123'", box)
```

Comment: It returns an error saying that the xpath string contains unresolvable namespaces..

Comment: Your script doesn't work on the box, but when i tried a similar script on the "go" button, it works. go=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button']") 
browser.execute_script("QueryAction.GoPage('TAB','123',200)", go)